# Second press required on cancel button

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I have a DialogBox with a cancel button called as follows:

```
 Dim dlgSizSelection As New dlgTyreSizeSelection(objCarWebVehicle.Tyres, objCarWebVehicle)

                If (dlgSizSelection.ShowDialog) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    selectedTyre = CType(dlgSizSelection.lstTyreOptions.SelectedItem, CarWebVehicleCOM.TyreData)
                    dlgSizSelection.Close()
                ElseIf (dlgSizSelection.ShowDialog) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
                    dlgSizSelection.Close()
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    MsgBox("No tyre sizes selected.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tyre Search")
                    dlgSizSelection.Close()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
```

However, when I set the DialogReturn property in the form its calling as follows:

```
DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
```

And press then cancel button, it flashes briefly then the dialog box reappears like I have pressed nothing and in order to get it to close fully I have to press it a second time.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please post the code where dlgTyreSizeSelection is defined?

Comment: Not necessary - the problem is clearly in the above code.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar OK, thanks for the correction. After seeing that both OK and Cancel options were doing the same and that he only complains about Cancel; I thought that there might be something wrong in the way in which dlgTyreSizeSelection is defined. But I guess that I should have analysed/tested the code before coming to this conclusion anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Don't call close after a modal dialog returns. A modal dialog closes itself automatically.

You code is problematic for the following reason: You're calling `ShowDialog` more than once. If your code determines that OK wasn't clicked, it shows the dialog *again*, waiting for the user to click again.

```
If (dlgSizSelection.ShowDialog) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    ...

ElseIf (dlgSizSelection.ShowDialog) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    ...
End If
```

Declare a local variable that holds the result of a *single call*  to `ShowDialog` and things will work fine:

```
Dim result as Windows.Forms.DialogResult = dlgSizSelection.ShowDialog

If (result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
  ....
ElseIf (result = Windows.Format.DialogResult.Cancel) Then
  ....
Else
  ....
End If
```

*Don't*  call `Close` and *no need* to `Exit Sub`.

Comment: Thanks, I got to the solution about two minutes after I posted here, I put the decision in a switch statement and only called the show method once. Thanks for the advice on the close methods. The Exit Sub needs to stay as it does stuff after this piece of code.